# How can I get the index number of the selected row in UIPICKERVIEW (iOS)

Tags: ios, indexing, uipickerview

I need the index number of the item that I have selected in my pickerview. I am able to get the row value thru objectatindex:row, however I need the index value when I click the done button that I have. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by index? You should be getting the row from pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:, and that row should correspond to an index in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out

```
 _lblResult.text=
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.pvTickets selectedRowInComponent:0]]
```